# c3js - having the X axis in the middle of the chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Is it possible to have the X axis in the middle of the graph?
When having Y values both negative and positive - and the X axis is on the 0 value
lets say similar to this image

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

## Positioning C3 x axis at a Desired y Value

### Method 1

Note that this method won't work if you have a `.load()` - see Method 2.

You can override the chart's `getTranslate` function to do this, like so

```
// get the original translate function
var originalTranslate = chart.internal.getTranslate;
chart.internal.getTranslate = function (target) {
    // if we are drawing the x axis
    if (target === 'x')
        // use the y scale to get the y position
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + this.y(0) + ")"
    else
        // otherwise just call the original function
        return originalTranslate.apply(this, [ target ]);
}
// redraw
chart.flush();
```

where chart is your C3 chart object

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3zpyu0yx/

### Method 2

Method 1 won't work when the data changes - because c3 stores the transitions (including those for the axis) and uses them when redrawing. So it never calls our updated `getTranslate` position for the new data and we are stuck with an animation that positions the scale at the 0 position of the *original* dataset.

One way to work around this would be to wait for transition to complete and then manually translate our axis. OR better still we could just update the transition for the x axis, like o

```
// select the x axis
d3.select(chart.element).select('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.axisX).transition()
    // and translate it to the y = 0 position
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + 0 + "," + chart.internal.y(0) + ")")
```

where chart is the C3 chart object.

You call this when you need the chart axis update. For a `.load()`, that would be within the `done` callback.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1hrd9g3k/

---

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is awsome. Can I trouble you some more (since it is a bit black box for me). The graph is a line graph with 2 y axis - and I want the line to align to the left y 0 (y and not y2)
Can You please change the answer to fit this?

Comment: strike the previous comment - my real problem - how should I act if I'm changing the data and calling .load()? It gets screwed up...

Comment: @Boaz - updated fiddle. Cheers! Go with the 2nd options anyway - its much simpler. I just kept the 1st answer because I didn't want to completely change the answer.

Comment: This doesnt work when u toggle the legend. Any fixes?